# How to add multiple pinpoints into GoogleMap in Titanium Framework for iphone?

Tags: titanium, google-maps-markers

I have used Googlemap using titanium framework for iphone,I am able to dispaly 1 pinpoint/marker for given location using latitude and longitude,but when i am going to display multiple markers/pinpoints , not able to show it on Map.

I have tried to create ARRAY of points to display on the google maps, but it is just showing single pinpoint to display it on Map.

Can anybody help me out for how to display multiple pinpoints to google map using tianium.

Any useful link or code will be appreciated!!

Thanks,
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample code and documentation

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Using+Location+services

It appears the link has changed:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Native+Maps+and+Annotations#NativeMapsandAnnotations-Annotations